# How to translate Virtue Mart 2.0 (Joomla e-comerce plugin)?

Tags: localization, joomla, translation, virtuemart, joomla1.7

I'm using Virtue Mart on joomla for catalogue features.And as I'm using joomla 1.7, I'm forced to use VirtueMart 2.0 that's still in RC state. I need to translate it to Ukrainian language because it's so new, that nobody have done it already.

Does anybody know where I should start? Because I've spent a lot of time looking for something like: **"VirtueMart 2.0 translation guide"** but I had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh… I've figured it out already. Her's what you should do:

1. Get the english files called **`en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini`** from `/language/en-GB` and `/administrator/language/en-GB`. First is for *front-end* "what the visitors see" and the second is for the *back-end* "admin panel".
2. Edit the file in any text editor. Just replace the words in quotes with what you need.
3. Change the beginning of the file to your language key and put it in the corresponding language directory in `/language` and `/administrator/language`. As for Ukrainian, the files will be renamed to **`uk-UA.com_virtuemart.ini`** and put in `/language/uk-UA` and `/administrator/language/uk-UA`.

I can also suggest using some version control to support translation, so you will see, what have you replaced with what.

If you want to make a package that could be installed with extension manager, you should read [Creating language packs for extensions in Joomla_1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_language_packs_for_extensions_in_Joomla_1.6)